# In what ways did Arabic influence Portuguese pronunciation or grammar?

Tags: gramática, pronúncia, linguística, história

I've read that Arabic strongly influenced the Portuguese language. Wikipedia lists [Portuguese *words* of Arabic origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Portuguese_words_of_Arabic_origin), but I have been wondering whether this influence is restricted to *words*, or whether Arabic also influenced the pronunciation or grammar of Portuguese.

Are there any features of Portuguese pronunciation or grammar, which can be traced to having their origins in Arabic?

*Please feel free to respond in Portuguese.*

Comment: Very relevant: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconquista

Comment: What a wonderful question! Would love to see some research that's been done on this.

Comment: Seguem 2 artigos que tangenciam o assunto. [Este] (http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/04/arabe-se-escreve-com-a/) explica a origem de diversos vocábulos do Português com origem árabe e a etimologia de alguns. Já [este] (http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/08/alcorao-ou-corao/) disserta sobre como pronunciar uma das palavras do Português com origem arábica.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parece haver um consenso que o árabe contribuiu para o português apenas com vocábulos, e, dentro destes, sobretudo com substantivos. Que a influência na gramática não poderia ser grande é claro para quem tenha aprendido francês: o francês não pode ter tido grande influência árabe, e a gramática francesa é parecidíssima com a portuguesa. Mas vejamos o que dizem autoridades mais avalizadas, com a [Infopédia:](https://www.infopedia.pt/$influencia-arabe-na-evolucao-da-lingua)

> Este estudo da relação entre a língua árabe e a língua portuguesa revela-nos que de entre o léxico de origem árabe predominam os substantivos, seguidos dos adjetivos. São muito escassos os advérbios e praticamente inexistentes os verbos, talvez pela diferença entre as duas línguas ser muito acentuada. 
>   Além do léxico não parece haver uma relação fonética ou morfológica. Nem mesmo da sintaxe.

Ou o filólogo [Antônio Houaiss, o do dicionário (“As Projeções da Língua Árabe na Língua Portuguesa”, comunicação na USP, 1986):](http://www.hottopos.com/collat7/houaiss.htm)

> Quando se considera a influência árabe no português, o único aspecto que ressalta é o da contribuição lexical, porque, realmente, não há razões — não houve, pode ser que venha a haver — para suspeitar que qualquer coisa, na área do sistema do árabe para o português, haja aparecido. Admitiu-se, durante algum tempo, que certa aspiração que o espanhol apresenta pudesse, por acaso, haver provindo da forte influência árabe. Mas, para a língua portuguesa, essa hipótese jamais foi formulada. Na área da sintaxe, nunca se admitiu, em hipótese alguma, que algo pudesse haver vindo do árabe, nem para o português nem para o espanhol.

A ideia que o árabe contribuiu sobretudo com substantivos está de acordo com a lista de vocábulos portugueses de origem árabe apresentada por [Cláudio Moreno (“Árabe se ecreve com A”, *Sua Língua*)](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/04/arabe-se-escreve-com-a/) no artigo referido acima pelo gmauch: à exceção da interjeição *oxalá*, são todinhos substantivos!

A importância dos vocábulos de origem árabe foi no passado muito maior do que é hoje. Diz Antônio Houaiss [(comunicação supracitada)](http://www.hottopos.com/collat7/houaiss.htm) que “num total de três mil a três mil e duzentas palavras do português primitivo, há, no mínimo, oitocentas palavras de origem árabe”, ou cerca de 25% do total. Ele estará a falar dos séculos XII a XIV. Depois disso terão sido adquiridas mais algumas palavras do árabe, mas as inovações passaram a vir sobretudo da Europa, e muitas das palavras de origem árabe anteriores foram caindo no esquecimento. Segundo José Pedro Machado, coordenador do dicionário em sete volumes da Sociedade da Língua Portuguesa (1958-71), existem atualmente 954 palavras portuguesas de origem árabe, mais de um terço das quais são arcaísmos ou caíram em desuso [(Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/influencia-arabe-na-lingua-portuguesa/5010).

Muitas coisas com nomes de origem árabe deixaram de ser usadas. Com o desuso do objeto o nome acabou por se perder também.Por exemplo, quem é que sabe o que é um [alqueire](http://www.aulete.com.br/alqueire)? Atenção que a resposta vem já a seguir. Eu só sei porque quando era criança havia em minha casa um meio-alqueire, uma caixa de madeira com capacidade de sete litros, usada para medir trigo, feijão e coisas assim. Já ninguém usa isso agora, e é natural que o próprio nome acabe por ser esquecido.

Comment: É, comparando com o francês parece que não tem assim tanta influência na gramática. Aproveito para dizer que gosto muito de ler as suas respostas.

Comment: Link incluído e muito obrigado.

Comment: Tinha esperança que os meus 100 pontitos aguçassem o apetite a mais gente, mas mais ninguém os quis... toma-os lá, por uma resposta que os merece bem!! :)

Comment: @ANeves Obrigado. Faz-se o que se pode. Na verdade eu já devia ter revisto isto há mais tempo. Dizer sobre o ponto central da questão "li, já não sei onde, que...", que era como estava, não era lá grande coisa. Foi uma das minhas primeiras respostas aqui. Tinha conhecido o site há três dias.