# Words with an "al-" prefix: do they really have Arabic origins?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, prefixos

There's a common assumption that if the word [begins with "al-" in Portuguese, it probably came from Arabic](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/al-).

Consider the following examples:

- [alarm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=alarm) (*alarme*)

  > early 14c., from Old French *alarme* (14c.), from **Italian** *all'arme* "to arms!" (literally "to the arms").
- [albino](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=albin)

  > 1777, from Spanish or Portuguese *albino*, from **Latin** *albus* "white" (see alb)
- [algae](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=algae) (*alga*)

  > 1794, from alga (singular), 1550s, from **Latin** *alga* "seaweed," which is of uncertain origin, perhaps from a PIE root meaning "to putrefy, rot."
- [allergic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=allergic) (*alérgico*)

  > 1911, from allergy + -ic; perhaps modeled on French allergique (1906)
- [allusive](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=allusive) (*alusivo*)

  > c. 1600, from **Latin** allus-, past participle stem of *alludere* + -ive
- [alluvial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=alluvial) (*aluvial*)

  > 1802, from **Latin** *alluvius* "alluvial" (from alluvium: "matter deposited by flowing water," 1660s, from **Medieval Latin** *alluvium*, neuter of *alluvius* "washed against," from Latin *alluere* "wash against," from ad- "to, against" (see ad-) + -luere, comb. form of lavere "to wash").
- [ally](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ally) (*aliado*)

  > late 13c., (...) from a differentiated stem of *aliier* (from **Latin** *alligare* "bind to;")
- [alter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=alter) (*alterar*)

  > late 14c., from **Medieval Latin** *alterare* "to change"
- [allumn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=alumnus) (ex-*aluno*)

  > 1640s, from **Latin** *alumnus* "a pupil," literally "foster son," vestigial present passive participle of *alere* "to nourish"

These are spread throughout several native European languages and their likely origin is Latin (was Latin influenced by Arabic?)...

Not focusing on nouns used for names of places <s>and particular (older) nouns (e.g.: [*alface*](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/alface/))</s>, how many words in Portuguese starting with "al-" really have Arabic origins? Perhaps answering this will provide some basis for an answer to an [harder question about Arabic influence in Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/408/156)...

Comment: I set out to answer this but realized I didn't quite know what sort of answer you're looking for. Many Portuguese words starting with *al-* do come from Arabic, although quite a few others do not. What about words Portuguese took from Spanish or another non-Arabic language but which had come to those languages from Arabic before passing into Portuguese? What about words that Portuguese took from Arabic instead of Latin or perhaps Greek, but which Arabic earlier itself took from Latin or Greek? What's the rule for these “particular (older) nouns not to focus on” beyond the place-names?

Comment: @tchrist I was less scrupulous than you were. I dealt with the request to exclude “particular (older) nouns” simply by ignoring the request. The overwhelming majority of *al*-words of non-Arabic origin come from Latin. I found a few of Castilian origin. Some of these look like they came from Latin (*alterne, alteroso*), other may well come from Arabic. The total count wouldn’t change much though.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for raising those questions, I understand and I was kind of expecting them. Considering that Latin "gave words" to Spanish and Portuguese, one of my goals with this was to track down if Latin was actually importing some of these words from Arabic and, if not, to compare the amount of  *al-* prefixed words existing in Portuguese coming from Latin with those coming from Arabic ([Jacinto](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1661/156) has already presented a nice comparison of these). Sorry about the nonsense of the "older" nouns part, I removed that from the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through my Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa and counted about 270 words beginning with ***al*** of Arabic origin and about 435 of non-Arabic origin. These do not include names of places, but include about ten demonyms.

[Wikipédia lists 197 Portuguese words of Arabic origin](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_palavras_portuguesas_de_origem_%C3%A1rabe), of which 96 begin with *al*. So *al*-prefixed words make up about half of all words of Arabic origin in the Wikipédia list. Assuming the same proportion in the Dicionário da Academia, would bring the gran total there to about 550 words, or about 0.8% of all entries.

Comment: Excellent, appreciated! Just to be clear from "Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa" there are 270+435=705 *al-* prefixed words that are not name of places and 38% of those are from Arabic origins, correct? I just didn't understand the comparison with the wikipedia list and how you calculate those final values (forget the "older" nouns I mentioned).

Comment: Correct: 270 + 435. 550 is to 270 as 197 is to 96, approximately.

Comment: @Armfoot, check whether the calculations are any clearer now.

Comment: All I know is that a lot of portuguese words do have an arabic origin,since the bigger parte of Portugal's territory centurys ago was governed by árabes and muslams. So it makes sence that a lot of words derive from arabic original but not all of tem. Also portuguese language is mostly founded and inspirated by latin